# Javascript explain the follow syntax

Tags: javascript, syntax, ecmascript-6

Could someone explain the follow JavaScript's syntax:

```
const result = (x, y) => (z) => { 
  
  /* code area */

  return something;
}
```

My assumptions:

> 1. (x, y) => (z) is a call to function z
> 2. (z) => { } is a call to whatever is inside { }

Questions:

1. If so, what would I expect to the code's flow?

   e.g: z is called first then it returns values to the anonymous function (x, y) => ?
2. Is the parentheses required?
3. About accessing the variables x, y and z in the code area, is it     possible?

Finally, could someone, please, give a basic example how to use/call this syntax.

If I missed something, you can find the full code (my syntax is a made up example) [here](https://github.com/jpuri/react-draft-wysiwyg/blob/master/src/renderer/index.js) or just ask me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's basically the same thing as this snippet of code:

```
const result = function(x, y) {
    return function(z) {
        // do stuff
    };
};
```

The handling of `this` is not the same as they are arrow functions but besides that it's the same.

So when you call a first time it will return you a function but the arguments are caught inside of the closure so you can use them inside of the function.

```
const partiallyApplied = result(3,4);
const value = partiallyApplied(7);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an `Arrow Functions` syntax from ES6 spec https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions . Translating it to the classic ES5 syntax will look like:

```
function (x, y) {
  return function (z) {
    /* code area */

    return something;
  }
}
```

The variables x, y and z are accessable at the `code area` of course.
The only difference in this case is that arrow functions don't have their own context, so `this` will refer to a parents' context (or `window`, if there is no any)